# How can I create a QVector or other container which can contain different widgets?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qvector

I am developing a GUI with Qt5, and in the main window of this GUI, it contains at least 4 tab widgets, and each tab widget will contain serval different child QWidgets, such as QLineEdit, QSpinBox, QLCDnumber, etc. Then when I open the tab, all its child widgets will appear.

Thus, for each tab, I decided to create a QVector(or another container type) to contain its all child Widgets,e.g.:

```cpp
QVector<QWidget*> wids;
```

for the first tab widget, if it has the following children:

```cpp
QLineEdit* line=new QLineEdit(this);
QLCDNumber* lcd=new QLCDNumber(this);
QSpinBox* spn=new QSpinBox(this);
```

then somehow I would like to do

```cpp
wids.append(line);
wids.append(lcd);
wids.append(spn);
```

and next,I want to operate each widget inside the tab,e.g.:

```cpp
wids[0]->setText("good");
wids[1]->display(1);
wids[2]->setRange(0,10);
```

I know I need to use **dynamic_cast<...>**, but I DO NOT KNOW how to do that,is ther anyone could give me some advice?

many thanks!

Comment: "I know I need to use dynamic_cast". When you knpw that, you know that your design is broken and it's time to re-think it. Why do you need a vector of widgets in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

`QLineEdit`, `QLCDNumber` and `QSpinBox` already inherit from `QWidget`. So if you put those in a `QVector` (or any container for that matter, could be a `std::vector<QWidget*>`) you have to deal with `QWidget` pointers.

As you correctly stated:

```cpp
wids.push_back(line);
wids.push_back(lcd);
wids.push_back(spn);
```

To get your respective classes back, for example `QLineEdit` back, you need to **downcast** from `QWidget` to `QLineEdit`, `QLCDNumber` or whatever else inherits from `QWidget`.

```cpp
QLineEdit * line = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(wids[0]);
```

This of course assumes that you know exactly at which position the object is located. You can of course test if your cast was successful:

```cpp
if( line == nullptr )
{
    // cast failed, either wids[0] is invalid or does not derive from QWidget
}

else
{
    // cast was successful, use 'line' as regular QLineEdit.
}
```

A one-liner, although being quite unsafe, would be:

```cpp
dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(wids[0])->setText("myText");
```

Comment: Glad I could help. You can read more about casts here:
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/12-9-dynamic-casting/

Comment: Hi again! sorry to disturb you！well I found an issue， when I want to add a QSlider in the tab, I am not able to append it to my **QVector<QWidget*> wids**, since the QSLider inherits from QAbstractSlider, and QAbstractSlider inherits from QObjects, i tried to create a **QVector<Object*> wids**, as all widgets inherit from QObject, it does not work, said"invalid conversion from 'QObject*' to 'QWidget*'",so it means I NEED to do the downcast twice?

Comment: You could always go with QObject* as the template type for the vector. So instead of a QVector<QWidget*>, maybe try a QVector<QObject*> as almost all Widgets inherit from QObject.

Comment: but of course there are exceptions to that as well.

Comment: HI, it works now! thanks again for your great help!